# Problem with applying inner glow to masked objects

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I made a rectangle, created a compound path and masked a image. My goal is to add a inner glow to created mask. How do i do that?

Answer (score 0):

the solution was simple. I just selected the entire clipped object and applied the effect!